# What does the velocity attribute represent in a Scroller

Tags: android

ScrollView.fling(int velocity);
What does velocity represent, how should I interpret it in order to use it?

Comment: according to the developer documenst velocity here is an int: The initial velocity in the Y direction. Positive numbers mean that the finger/cursor is moving down the screen, which means we want to scroll towards the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I describes the initial velocity in Y-direction. The unit is *pixels/second*. So the higher (positive) the number is the faster you scroll to the top. The lower (negative) it is the faster you scroll to the bottom.

It's described in the documentation of `android.widget.OverScroller`